# SQL Query to query data hierarchically in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, hana

I have the following table, which has a list of subjects and objects related with the same relationship.

```
    |---------------------------------------|
    |Subject    |Relationship    |Object    |
    |---------------------------------------|
    |A          |x               |B         |
    |B          |x               |C         |
    |B          |x               |D         |
    |C          |x               |E         |
    |D          |x               |F         |
    |P          |x               |G         |
    |---------------------------------------|
```

My need is to write a SQL to get all the related **Subjects** and **Objects** given an initial subject.

For example:

1. If "C" is given as the initial subject, output should be "C" and "E" (because "C" related to "E" with "x")
2. If "A" is given as the initial subject, output should be "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" and "F". Explanation,

   - "A" is related to "B"
   - "B" is related to "C" and "D"
   - "C" is related to "E"
   - "D" is related to "F"

Comment: SAP Hana and Microsoft SQL Server are two very different DBMS. Which one are you really using?

Comment: I am using both, I need to comeup with a query for both DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursive query

```
with rcte as
(
  select * 
  from data
  where subject = 'a'
  union all
  select d.* 
  from data d
  join rcte r on r.object = d.subject
)
select r.subject from rcte r
union
select r.object from rcte r
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=78fdcc5e5768c7480486aa6175631560)

Comment: SQL Server supports Recursive CTE expressions but HANA does not support it using SQLScript, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use recursion:

```
DECLARE @Subject char(1) = 'A'

;WITH cte AS (  -- Your table sample
    SELECT  [Subject],
            [Relationship],
            [Object]
    FROM (VALUES
    ('A' ,'x' ,'B'),
    ('B' ,'x' ,'C'),
    ('B' ,'x' ,'D'),
    ('C' ,'x' ,'E'),
    ('D' ,'x' ,'F'),
    ('P' ,'x' ,'G')
    ) as t([Subject],[Relationship],[Object])
), rec AS ( -- Recursive CTE
    SELECT [Object]
    FROM cte 
    WHERE [Subject] = @Subject
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.[Object]
    FROM cte c
    INNER JOIN rec r
        ON r.[Object] = c.[Subject]
)

SELECT @Subject
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM rec
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
D
F
E
```

Answer (score 1):

SAP HANA doesn't support general recursive common table expressions (CTEs). 
Instead, for one very common use case like this one (hierarchy processing), a specific set of functions is available (with HANA 2 SP2):

```
with h as (SELECT * FROM HIERARCHY (
            SOURCE (select "Subject" as parent_id, 
                            "Object" as node_id 
                    from rels
                    order by "Subject" asc)
            ORPHAN ROOT ))
SELECT 
     node_id
FROM    
    HIERARCHY_DESCENDANTS (
         SOURCE h
         START WHERE parent_id ='A');
```

With the `HIERARCHY` function HANA creates a hierarchy data structure from your input data. I named your table `rels` in this example.
The `SOURCE` part declares how the source table/view shall be interpreted to make up a hierarchy. `ORPHAN ROOT` declares that nodes that are not connected to another node are made "root" nodes. That is to say, that hierarchies don't have to be proper cycle free trees, but can have orphan nodes as well as multiple roots and cycles.

This hierarchy construction is captured in the common table expression `h`, but could also be put into a view or materialised into a (temporary) table.

The next step is using the `HIERARCHY_DESCENDANTS` function to have HANA "walk down" the hierarchy branch starting with the 'A' node.
This results in

```
NODE_ID
B      
C      
E      
D      
F
```

The starting node can be "unioned" to the result set if necessary.

More details on the hierarchy functionality can be found in the HANA documentation [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/fc59f81a5c494f399cc2ff70b9c3b4c9.html)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description Lars Br. I am on SAP HANA version is 1.00.12210, so unfortunately `HIERARCHY` function is not an option.